# Creating a Class in C#, which file should I use?

Tags: c#, class, mono, xamarin, monogame

As I told you in a question before, I'm starting to learn **C#** and right now I'm beginning with the classes theory, so when I was going to create a class I found there was two 'templates' to do it **[I'm using Xamarin on a Mac],** one under **C#** -> General, and the other one in **C# -> MonoGame.** Both seems pretty much the same, but I want to know which one should I use, or what are the differences between both?

This is the one located in General:

```
using System;

namespace Application
{
    public class stack
    {
        public stack ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the one in MonoGame:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Application
{
    class stack
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections Hardeep, english is not my mother tongue and mac's autocorrect is the best troll you'll find in the world, everytime I write something in english it starts to change words and delete characters randomly... I guess I'll have to take a second look before I post a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `using System` is the basic framework that needs to be uploaded to do thing like `Console.write()`. With out it, you'd have to do `System.Console.write`.

In your second example, you are just importing other framework that you might need depending on what you are developing. From the looks of it, it is a basic game framework set: audio, graphics, touch, etc.

The `using` is just a way to import frameworks that you might need. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhdeatwt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Both the code you displayed are correct.

The second one contains the namespace references for your application.

For example :

```
using System.Text;
```

The `System.Text` namespace contains classes that represent ASCII and Unicode character encodings; abstract base classes for converting blocks of characters to and from blocks of bytes; and a helper class that manipulates and formats String objects without creating intermediate instances of String.